# How to run The Grinder in MAC?

Tags: grinder

I trying to use the grinder testing framework in mac, but i cant get the pass the first steps to open the console. this is what i tried: 
i added class path and try to run it like this from the terminal with this command

```
java net.grinder.Console
```

but i get  this error :

```
Error running worker process (org/picocontainer/ComponentFactory)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/picocontainer/ComponentFactory
    at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.run(GrinderProcess.java:309)
    at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.run(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:86)
    at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.main(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.picocontainer.ComponentFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:229)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

this is the [tutorial im following](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/getting-started.html#howtostart), anybody have some thoughts on this.

Comment: You haven't put any part of the tool in your classpath, so of course the class won't be found. Please learn about -cp and classpaths and apply what you learn to this problem.

Comment: thats the thing that puzzle me i tried cp like this **/path-to-java/bin/java -cp /path-to-grinder/lib/grinder.jar** also i tried export **export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path-to-grinder/lib/grinder.jar** but i still have this issue.

Comment: You didn't write that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grinder has a much longer classpath than just 'grinder.jar'. You need all the dependencies on the classpath, too. (e.g. picocontainer)

If the grinder jar has a MANIFEST.MF, it might list them, in which case those jars just have to be sitting in the same directory as the grinder jar. If not, you need to set the classpath to include them.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error message you are showing will be fixed by adding picocontainer-.jar to your classpath.  But you will probably need to include everything in the grinder lib dir on your classpath to get things working properly.